# Merge statement with Db link is not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge, dblink

Merge statement with Db link is working fine normally .
The same merge when written inside the procedure is also working fine.
But, when I have scheduled the job for the same procedure, it is throwing error.

Tool used: Oracle SQL Developer

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified--ORA-06512:**

Please help in identifying the issue.

Comment: Are you referring to a global database link, or a private one; and if private, is the job running as the same user that you tested the procedure with?

Comment: Exactly _how_ are you scheduling the job?  The symptoms suggest your db is on *nix and you are scheduling through cron.  When you do that, your script does _NOT_ inherit any environment variables( like ORACLE_HOME, from which the location of tnsnames.ora is derived) , and so is necessary to set them itself.

Comment: @EdStevens: DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB  is being used here which is scheduled to run every 30 mins and on each run it is getting failed

Comment: @AlexPoole: Its a provate DB link which was created using ALIAS name and not using TNS entry.

Comment: _"DB link which was created using ALIAS name and not using TNS entry."_   Are you saying the USING property of the db link is the name of an alias instead of a tnsname?  Show us the DDL for the db_link (you can mask the password).

Comment: @EdStevens: It worked when DB link was created using TNS. Thanks .

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what you mean by 'alias name' vs tns entry.  The tns entry _is_ an alias - that gets resolved to an actual net address by the entry in tnsnames.  I'm glad you got it fixed, but I'd be really curious to see what you had - what you were calling 'alias name' - when it wasn't working.  If we saw that we could comment on the root cause.